# heroku logs --tail Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, heroku-cli

I'm deploying a node.js app on heroku, the code look like this:

index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Hello to Memories API");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`) ) )
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Procfile

```
web: npm run start
```

I don't know why I get Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch node.js error. Any help would be appreciated.

In addition im my env file I removed PORT for heroku but I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: What is the `start` script in your `package.json`? Is your `.env` file committed?

Comment: It's nodemon index.js

Comment: https://ibb.co/L0T5RCw

Comment: Why would you switch from nice code blocks to an image? [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, [edit] your question and add a code block. (Also, when using images to supplement your question please always use the _official_ image host _only_. You can do that by pasting your image while editing. Third-tier image hosts like ibb.co are entirely unreliable.